# Python subprocess.check_output output differ from bash output of same command

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, subprocess

I'm trying to get the current bash version from python using subprocess.

In my terminal, I can use `printf "%s\n" $SHELL` to get `/bin/bash` and `printf "%s\n" $BASH_VERSION` to get `5.1.8(1)-release`.

So I prepared this python script:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['printf "%s\n" $SHELL'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b'/bin/bash\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['printf "%s\n" $BASH_VERSION'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
b'\n' <-- This output is wrong
```

Anyone could explain me why the output of printf $BASH_VERSION in subprocess differ from the terminal one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BASH_VERSION` is an [internal variable](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) to bash shell, it simple doesn't exists outside of it. As per https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh

So if /bin/sh on your system is not an alias to bash - you won't get anything. To specify shell explicitly, you could either call it, or use `executable` as kwarg.

Some tests that i ran on my system, where /bin/sh linked to /usr/bin/bash

```
subprocess.check_output(['echo $BASH_VERSION'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)                                                                                              
b'4.4.23(1)-release\n'

subprocess.check_output(['echo $BASH_VERSION'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, executable='/bin/zsh')                                                                       
b'\n'

subprocess.check_output(['echo $BASH_VERSION'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, executable='/bin/bash')                                                                      
b'4.4.23(1)-release\n'
```

Note that in second example i invoke `zsh` which doesn't have this variable

`$SHELL` variable is actually inherited by subshells from your actual shell, but it doesn't mean that command is actually ran using that SHELL.

In my case, my user has `zsh` as default shell, but running

```
bash -c "echo $SHELL"                                                                                                                        
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Will still return zsh, as you can see

Answer (score 0):

`$SHELL` is misleading, and not telling you what you think it is. The second command (showing `$BASH_VERSION`) is correct; `subprocess.check_output()` is running the command under /bin/sh, which is [dash instead of bash in recent versions of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) (and many other linux distros), so `BASH_VERSION` is not set in that shell.

Contrary to popular belief, the `SHELL` variable does not indicate the currently executing shell. bash will generally set it to the *current user's default shell*. From the [bash manual section on "Bash Variables"]:

> `SHELL`
> This environment variable expands to the full pathname to the
> shell. If it is not set when the shell starts, Bash assigns to it the
> full pathname of the current user’s login shell.

So if your default shell (as defined in someplace like /etc/passwd) is /bin/zsh, and you manually run a bash shell under that, it'll set `SHELL` to "/bin/zsh" even though you're actually running bash at the time.

Shells other than bash may or may not set `SHELL` to anything at all (note that it's listed in the "Bash Variables", not the ["Bourne Shell Variables"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) section with the variables other Bourne-family shells use). dash and zsh don't set `PATH` at all, and ksh seems to do something else with it.

So, you may ask, if `subprocess.check_output()` runs under dash, why is it printing anything at all for `$SHELL`? I suspect it's because it inherited that from your interactive bash shell. If you started a zsh shell and ran `echo $SHELL` in that, you'd presumably see "/bin/bash" there too.